# How to add users in groups in LDAP and ALFRESCO simultaneously

Tags: ldap, alfresco, openldap, spring-ldap, ldapconnection

My LDAP and alfresco server both are in sync.Is there any way through which when I am adding a user in a group (groupOfNames) LDAP I will be able to add it in alfresco at the same time(simulataneously).
I have defined groups as an (groupOfNames) and I am assigning users through "memeber" attribute.

Comment: Do you really need the users to appear simultaneously in alfresco and  LDAP ? I you think so, what is the reason ?

Answer (score 2):

Simultaneously is not possible. What you can do is change the cronjob of the group sync so it runs every minute/15 seconds for example.

```
synchronization.import.cron=0 0/1 * * * ?
```